# How to extract elements inside of a <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, getelementsbytagname

As a coding newbie I'm following a tutorial on the map function which gives this example

> As a datasource we'll use HackerNews' big RSS feed and since we can treat RSS as > plain HTML, it's very simple to get started:

```
var titles = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
```

When I run this command I don't get anything back, when I inspect the page, I see that all the data and tags are enclosed inside of a top level  tag. I can run document.getElementsByTagName('pre') which returns everything, but not the specific title tags.

Any help on understanding this and working around it would be useful.

Comment: Could you link the tutorial?

Comment: @Wheezykw http://jcla1.com/blog/javascript-mapreduce/  This is the actual page that I'm trying to get the elements out of - https://news.ycombinator.com/bigrss

Comment: In your browser console, run your command and then type titles. You will get an HTML collection. If you click on the HTML collection, you will see each title you returned contains lots of properties of the tag to include the text property which has your title name in it.

Comment: The next example on the page shows you how to retrieve the properties of each title.

Comment: @Wheezykw I've followed their instructions exactly and all I get back is an empty array. If I goto https://news.ycombinator.com/bigrss and then run var titles = document.getElementsByTagName('title'); in the console - I'm not seeing it returning anything.

If I run this command which they show further down the page, I still see no results:


    var titles=
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('title'))
  .    map(function(node) {
        return node.innerText;
      });

Comment: Type titles again in the console. The first time you run the command you are setting the variable. The second time returns the value of the variable.

Comment: Looking at news.ycominator.com/bigrss ...They only have a title for the page. You are going to want to target the text of the span embedded in the anchor tag. Right click and inspect element should let you see the html and then you can decide what properties of elements you are targeting.

Comment: @Wheezykw I did try typing titles a second time, nothing is being returned though, it's empty.

Comment: @Wheezykw I don't know what you mean about the title for the page? I think you must have missed something in the question or the links I sent you.

Comment: @j obe The code you linked in your original question is what I ran.

Comment: @Wheezykw Ok but where did you run it, it needs to be run on the rss link, this is the data that only has a <pre> element in the dom and where I am stuck. Unfortunately still in the same boat as this morning regarding this problem.

Comment: Any help on this....anyone please?

Comment: When you run that code you are going to get the tag named 'title'. You can replace it with 'p' to return all paragraphs on the page. I would recommend inspecting the rss page and decide what tag you want to search for.

Comment: Try `var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');`

This will get you an HTMLCollection object that contains all the spans for the page. You'll have to follow the next block of code on the tutorial to get just the innerHTML property for each span on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the  element that was being applied to the data is being added by Chrome. In FireFox it's possible to see all the rss data properly and continue with the tutorial.

I'm not sure why one browser renders all the dom nodes while Chrome just hides them in pre tags, but that's the reason the query didn't work in Chrome.